# how to auto deploy with msbuild correctly?

Tags: msbuild

i have triggered a build definition and build succeeded, the build definition is assigned the following parameters which i want to do some auto deploy stuff:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:Configuration=Debug 
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true 
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true 
/p:DeployIISAppPath=BlueOffice/BlueOfficeService  /*site/application*/
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=http://10.1.1.4 
/p:username=mobiledomain\tfsbuild2 
/p:password=Abcd1234!
```

but when the build finished, the deployment not be done, anything about project or build definition i should notice to modify?thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,
Can you give more details like, which build template you are using and whether your workflow / build script invokes MSDeploy?

Comment: the build template is by default, i haven't put any scripts. i just create my definition and give it my deploy parameters listed above.